# Ubuntu 18.04 screen freezes after startup

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, screen, freeze

Hi everyone I have this issue only recently. I've been using ubuntu 18.04 for more than 2 months. But today when I start up the screen freezes [frozen screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4k0o.jpg). I tried all the possible key combination ctl+alt+f1 (f2,f3) at the frozen screen but nothing work. Even I tried this https://digitalfortress.tech/debug/what-should-you-do-when-ubuntu-freezes/ and this https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ but none worked either. [Attached GNU image of my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PITa5.jpg). Further information is I'm using rtx 2070 and nvidia release 418 driver if that's relevant.

I'm really worried as I cannot access my work. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: have you tried booting into the Recovery mode ?  on boot hold down Shift key until grub menu appears then use arrow keys to navigate to one saying Recovery then hit enter ... get into root option ... save your data to USB stick ... look for graphics driver related errors in output of running ... dmesg ... look in /var/log/ as well

Comment: @ScottStensland I tried recovery mode but nothing changed. I'm planning on mounting my data and reinstall everything. I can access the log message from dmesg but I don't know what to look for

Comment: So I got some red lines such as: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key and Unhandled alg: 0x707. How should I go with this?